# Reading latest data from Kafka broker in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I want to receive the latest data from Kafka to Flink Program, but Flink is reading the historical data.
I have set `auto.offset.reset` to `latest` as shown below, but it did not work

```
properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
```

Flink Programm is receiving the data from Kafka using below code

```
//getting stream from Kafka and giving it assignTimestampsAndWatermarks

        DataStream<JoinedStreamEvent> raw_stream = envrionment.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<JoinedStreamEvent>("test",
                new JoinSchema(), properties)).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new IngestionTimeExtractor<>());
```

I was following the discussion on
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4280 , which suggests adding the source in below mentioned way

```
Properties props = new Properties();
...

FlinkKafkaConsumer kafka = new FlinkKafkaConsumer("topic", schema, props);
kafka.setStartFromEarliest();
kafka.setStartFromLatest();
kafka.setEnableCommitOffsets(boolean); // if true, commits on checkpoint if checkpointing is enabled, otherwise, periodically.
kafka.setForwardMetrics(boolean);
...

env.addSource(kafka)
```

I did the same, however, I was not able to access the `setStartFromLatest()`

```
 FlinkKafkaConsumer09 kafka = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<JoinedStreamEvent>( "test", new JoinSchema(),properties);
```

> What should I do to receive the latest values that are being sent to
>   Kafka rather than receiving values from history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by creating the new `group id` named `test1` both for the sender and consumer and keeping the topic name same as `test`.

> Now I am wondering, is this the best way to solve this issue? because
> every time I need to give a new group id
>
> Is there some way I can just read data that is being sent to Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could work for you. It did for me. Modify the properties and your kafka topic.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();


        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "ip:port");
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "ip:port");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "your-group-id");


        DataStream<String> stream = env
                .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("your-topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));



        stream.writeAsText("your-path", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
            .setParallelism(1);

        env.execute();

    }
```